# variable value added but array don't get pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does the value gets added but array don't get pushed?

I figured, if I add the `window.load` after function it works. I get that when it's initially parsed, function doesn't run but, this case I'm calling the function soon after window loads.

Regardless, why are variables getting the value but not the array? Am I really using `window.load` in a stupid way? Learning here.

```
window.load = foo(); //works if I declare this after the function

var barr = [],
    max, min;

function foo() {
    var a = 10,
        b = 30;

    barr.push("asfd");
    min = Math.min(a, b);
    max = Math.max(a, b);
    console.log(barr); // IDK what does this log, DevTool just throws error straight away
};

console.log(barr); // logs empty array [] as initially declared
console.log(min); // logs 10 on global scope
console.log(max); // logs 30 on global scope
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `window.onload = foo();` to

```
window.onload = foo;
```

By using `foo()` here will call the function immediately and assign the returned value to the `onload` callback. So, before declaring any variables `foo` is called. When you use `foo` to assign function to `onload` event, function reference of `foo` is passed.

Also, I'd recommend you to use `DOMContentLoaded` event instead of `onload` as `onload` will be fired when all the resources on the page are completely loaded which will take too long.

It is considered a good practice to define functions before referencing them. As function declarations(`function fnName()`) are hoisted to the top, it'll work. But if the function is created using function expression syntax(`var fnName = function() {...`), an error will be thrown.

```js
var barr = [],
  max, min;

function foo() {
  var a = 10,
    b = 30;

  barr.push("asfd");
  min = Math.min(a, b);
  max = Math.max(a, b);
  console.log(barr); // ["asfd"]
};

window.onload = foo;
// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', foo, false);

console.log(barr); // logs empty array [] as initially declared
console.log(min); // logs undefined
console.log(max); // logs undefined
```

---

One more thing to note here is that the variables `min` and `max` will be `undefined` as they are not assigned value. If you log them after `foo` is executed, they'll log correct values.

Comment: Also the event handler is window.onload not window.load

Comment: Thanks, but did you try running your code? I did and array is still not getting pushed. I once got values of min and max but barr undefined with `window.onload` but can't reproduce it again.

I get your point regarding min and max but array should have got pushed right?

Comment: @Tushar Yeah I just noticed the answer, you edited it few times. So if I use anonymous function approach then min and max will also log correct values? Thanks!

Comment: @СхирисхШреста If you call the function `foo` and then try to log the variables, you'll get their respective values. So, yes, if you use anonymous function and then wrap the code in it it'll log correct values.

Comment: @Tushar I figured out how to work it out. Thanks. One tiny thing that, if I use anonymous approach, how or what do I refer to when using `onload` or `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: @СхирисхШреста Check http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jfo2y7a4/ for anonymous function